# How to find iframe inside Div using WatiN?

Tags: iframe, watin

There are options to find other elements inside iframe/frame or inside div but I was not able to find any option to find iframe inside Div.
There are methods like ElementWithTag which give me Element but there is no cast available to convert Element to Frame or may be I am missing something.

Below code gives me error.

`Frame details = (Frame)structureContent.ElementWithTag("iframe", Find.ByName("details")).NativeElement;
Frame portal = detailsDisplay.Frame(Find.ByName("portalDisplay"));`

`$exception {"Unable to cast object of type 'WatiN.Core.Native.InternetExplorer.IEElement' to type 'WatiN.Core.Frame'."}`

When I tried to search I get results only for finding elements or div under iframe , so please help me guys.
Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the HTML of the iframe?

Comment: `<div id="pvTab"> <iframe name="myfrn"></iframe></div>` Actually I want to create extension for Div like we have `browser.Frames` so can we have something like `Div div = ...; div.Frames;`

Comment: Did you try this
`Frame myFrame = structureContent.Frame(Find.ByName("myfrn"));`

Comment: There is no method `.Frame` for div or other elements. It is only for browser and frame or domcontainer.